# toString() of Undefined in Universally Rendered(React&Express&AltJS) through Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, flux

I have a strange issue and I'm not sure what part of my stack is responsible for throwing the error. I currently have an es6/webpack/react-router rc2/flux(altjs) isomorphically(universally) rendered application. If there are any bugs on any part of the frontend(syntax error or otherwise) or an api endpoint is incorrect/not responding the appropriate data format(i.e. an array isn't being sent back which therefore cannot be mapped over by one of my react components) the server crashes with the following error

> Cannot read property statuscode.toString() of undefined

Is this react-router related? Webpack related? React related? I wish I could have a more informative stack trace because as I work through the backend as I'm not sure what is incorrect, whether it is front-end code or backend code. Is there any way to "catch" what is occurring. To clarify nothing else changes but the expected data structure which throws this error.

Edit:

```
export default class Dashboard extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: DataStore.getState().data
    };
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className='dashboard'>
            <Tile gridWidth='cute-6-laptop' linkTo='/data/temperature/water' size='regularTile' title='Water Temperature'>
                <OverviewChart data={this.state.data.Water_Demand.devices} mapObj={mapObjs.water} keyData={[{key: null, value: this.state.data.Water_Demand.devices[2].readings[this.state.data.Water_Demand.devices[2].readings.length - 1].rate, units: this.state.data.Water_Demand.devices[2].rateUnits}]} chartClass='interiorTemperature' includeNavChart={false} includeBarChart={false} w='473' h='180'/>
            </Tile>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: All we can tell is that `statuscode` is undefined from this, you didn't provide any other code so I don't think anyone is able to guess the cause of that

Comment: That's fair I just assumed that it was more related to React's failure to render serverside due to incorrect assumed data format during hydration. In this case this is where Overviewchart is located and if the data is not in the precise expected format structure, this error is thrown. I've updated the question with some code.